# My facebook login button works using omniauth, but I don't get to the "allow" screen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, omniauth

I've added a facebook login button using the omniauth-facebook gem.  It does the roundtrip to facebook and back with the omniauth.auth hash and all of the user's info.  But I don't get the intermediary page where the user allows my app, so when I try to post to facebook from my app I get the error

```
OAuthException :: (#200) The user hasn't authorized 
the application to perform this action)
```

I'm guessing that this is a setting on the facebook apps page, but for the life of me I don't see it or see mention in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, I should have been reading the omni auth-facebook documentation more closely.  In the docs:

> scope: A comma-separated list of permissions you want to request from
>   the user. See the Facebook docs for a full list of available
>   permissions:
>   http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions.
>   Default: email,offline_access